# How to resolve Cross Side Scripting for AJAX requests in JSF

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, xss

I have been working in trying to find a solution to cross side scripting for AJAX request

So this is how the flow is:

1) A screen has a text box where we are using a RichEditor

2) In the text box you can click Edit Button which shows displays a new panel

3) Once you click, the new panel is open, and in the new panel you can Edit the text and Update it.

4) In the new panel there is a Continue Button, if you click on it will update the text in the backing bean, close the new panel, and refresh the text area in the original panel.

When continue is clicked, onComplete, they hide the new panel or current panel and rerender the original panel(There is an AJAX request for this). So while we send that request, our security team uses Paros Tool to insert malicious scripts (alert('XSS attack!')) on it. Since it is an AJAX request and it goes through an AJAX Engine to get a response, I have not been able to figure out how to filter or make sure the scripts would not run if is bad script.

Possibly, a Javascript needs to be run right after an AJAX response, but I am not sure how to do that. Basically my goal is to avoid cross side scripting, if someone uses an external tool to put malicious code in AJAX request.

We are using JSF 1.2 and RichFaces.

Here is the code Snippet of Original Panel:

```html
<tr valign="top">
<td><h:outputText styleClass="formLabel" value="Text:" /></td>
<td colspan="3">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="formTextMiddle" border="0" id="TextGroupFrom_aPanel">
        <div class="editTemplateSmallScrollBar">
            <ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.template.Parts}" var="part">
                <a4j:commandLink ajaxSingle="true"
                    action="#{backingBean.editpart}"
                    rendered="#{part.widget}"
                    reRender="#{backingBean.panelName}Panel,#{backingBean.reRenderList}"
                    oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('#{backingBean.panelName}Panel',{top:200});">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{part.generatedName}" target="#{backingBean.partName}" />
                    <h:graphicImage value="/img/#{part.image}" style="border:0" alt="#{part.generatedName}" />
                </a4j:commandLink>
                <h:outputText value="#{part.value}" escape="false" rendered="#{!part.widget}" />                                                                                                    
            </ui:repeat>
        </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the code snippet for the new panel which opens up:

```html
<h:panelGroup>
    <a4j:commandButton styleClass="rich-button" align="right"
        oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity!='Error'}) {Richfaces.hideModalPanel('aPanel');reRenderTextFrom_aPanel();}"
        value="Continue" action="#{backingBean.updateParts}">
    </a4j:commandButton>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="reRenderTextFrom_aPanel" reRender="TextGroupFrom_aPanel"></a4j:jsFunction>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Well, you can *inject* the JavaScript value for your text, but that's not a security hole. I would worry if I reload the data and the script is executed in client side, which doesn't happen with JSF if used properly. Or are you asking about how to sanitize your text data?

Comment: I can sanitize it but the problem as stated above is that an external tool can be used to inject Javascript code in an AJAX request. So how will I resolve that in JSF?

Comment: Again, that's not a problem. You can even do that in google search queries. The exploit arises when that piece of javascript code gets executed after loading the data in your browser. If that happens then start worrying, if not then do nothing or establish rules to remove all malicious code at server side.

Comment: The script is getting executed in the browser that's why I am asking the question.

Comment: Oh ok. As stated in my first comment, that should not happen if you use JSF properly. Which field or part of your page is the one that loads the malicious code?

Comment: As in the code: onComplete calls a function reRenderTextFrom_aPanel() . That function rerenders TextGroupFrom_aPanel, which is that original panel. So when that Ajax request is made, it is trapped through a Paros tool and malicious jab scripts are being put. The malicious code runs when re rendering that panel. @BalusC any solution would help. Thanks!

Comment: The one that is printing the malicious script is <h:outputText value="#{part.value}" escape="false" rendered="#{!part.widget}" /> where part.value is running the script.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The previous issue was more for when a request is interecepted with an external tool(and put the malicious code inside the request)and saved to the database. This one is more on the fly. I am sorry that I did not provide a proper feedback for the previous as I have not been able to reach a proper solution yet. We have been using escape=false because outputText would not display special characters properly without it meaning it will display the encoded value itself. Let me know if that clarifies. I just need to put escape=false but still avoid these scripts

Comment: If there is possibility of doing a regex when it is being rerendered?

Comment: The problem is that the trapped request or the ajax request is receiving its response from Ajax Engine (the malicious script is placed in the trapped request). It is everything to do with AJAX and javascript. If it were to go to backing bean then I could use Jsoup but for rerendering it is not going to the backing bean. In a way understand what you are saying but no matter how much one sanitizes the external could replace it with malicious script. So, there should be some client side sanitization while being rerendered.

Comment: Please do not assume that the user is a normal user putting malicious script in the text area. The use case is that the user is a hacker using a hacking tool called paros which can trap request and response. So in the trapped request the hacker replaces the text completely with malicious scripts. Thats why I am talking about making a client side script that sanitizes just before it rerenders. So an ideal solution would be a script(to sanitize) which runs right before the it renders in the browser after it receives the Ajax response.

Comment: The complication comes on how to do this in JSF, how to run a script which runs right before the Ajax response gets rendered from the browser. How to run a javascript as it will not be going to the backing bean as the user is a hacker. Thanks for the help and support. I am hopeful to get any kind of solution to this.